# Starting 3d game development

Tags: ios, 3d, physics

I want to try myself in 3d game development for iOS. And so I want to create a simple game just to see how the things work. In this game I want to have a level designed in max or blender and imported in my game. This level should include physics (for example some walls on a plane). I'm thinking about using Bullet phys engine. And I want to have a character that is able to move on this level (the walk have to be animated).

Please provide me some tutorials, source code or suggest some books.
Also it will be great suggesting some game engines to use!

Comment: Check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ , perhaps?

Comment: I hope you have fun doing that. It sounds like you will.

Comment: This is pretty open-ended and broad. You'll find better answers if you search for tutorials on your own, try a few things, and come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Unity for iOS http://unity3d.com/

Comment: i have the same question you had a year ago. You have accepted unity3d as answer. can you please eloborate bit more on unity3d, about the learning curve, return on investment etc. Appreciate your help